# merging data.tables based on columns names

Tags: r, data.table

I am trying to do some left-join merges with data.tables.
The package description quote that

> In all joins the names of the columns are irrelevant; the columns of x's key are joined to in order

I understand that I can use `.data.table[` and `data.table:::merge.data.table`

What I would like is : merge X and Y specifying the keys (like by.x and by.y in base merge, ->why taking this away ?)

Let's suppose I have

```
DT = data.table(x=rep(c("a","b","c"),each=3),y=c(1,3,6),v=1:9,key="x,y,v")
DT1 = data.frame(x1=c("aa","bb","cc"),y1=c(1,3,6),v1=1:3,key="x1,y1,v1")
```

and I would like this output:

```
#data.table:::merge is masking I don't know how to call the base version of merge anymore
R) {base::merge}(DT,DT1,by.x="y",by.y="y1") 
y x v x1 v1
1 1 a 1 aa  1
2 1 c 7 aa  1
3 1 b 4 aa  1
4 3 a 2 bb  2
5 3 b 5 bb  2
6 3 c 8 bb  2
7 6 b 6 cc  3
8 6 a 3 cc  3
9 6 c 9 cc  3
```

I am very happy to use `[` or `data.table:::merge` but I would like an option that do not modify `DT` or `DT1` (like changing the column names and calling merge and changing it back)

Comment: `merge.data.table` is a method for the S3 generic base function `merge`. To call the base merge, `merge.data.frame(DT,DT1,by.x="y",by.y="y1")` should work. But see my answer too.

Comment: see the new post [data-table inner/outer join to merge with NA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14076065/data-table-inner-outer-join-to-merge-with-na)

Comment: Btw, I just noticed your two attempts to post to datatable-help from Nabble. They haven't got through (see yellow band at the top in Nabble) because you need to subscribe to datatable-help first. Nabble asks you "are you a member of the list you're trying to post to" at the point of posting. It's easy and automatic to join. It's just a spam prevention measure.

Comment: I know this is old, but shouldn't it be possible to get around this by renaming one of the columns in the data.table to match the other data.table? I've tried this using setnames and come up with an error, but I don't see why it shouldn't work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Update:** Since **data.table** v1.9.6 (released September 19, 2015), `merge.data.table()` does accept and nicely handles arguments `by.x=` and `by.y=`. [Here's an updated link](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/637) to the FR (now closed) referenced below.

---

Yes this is a feature request not yet implemented :

[FR#2033  Add by.x and by.y to merge.data.table](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2033&group_id=240&atid=978)

There isn't anything preventing it. Just something that wasn't done. I very rarely need `merge` and was slow to realise its usefulness more generally. We've made good progress in bringing `merge` performance as fast as `X[Y]`, and this feature request is at the highest priority. If you'd like it more quickly you are more than welcome to add those arguments to `merge.data.table` and commit the change yourself.  We try to keep source code short and together in one function/file, so by looking at `merge.data.table` source hopefully you can follow it and see what needs to be done.

Comment: I can try to have a look (It is probably above my level though), I would need to set up a svn/git though I guess...

Comment: I doubt it's much beyond your level, the source of merge is just R and X[Y] calls, which you are getting to know already. It might be a good exercise to pick off actually. If `data.table` was on github would it be easier for you?

Comment: can you read the message bellow because I fear a bug in the Y[X] itself (or a feature) but if you look at left outer join bellow Y[X] shows ligns it should not :( (I hope I am wrong)

Comment: @statquant Oops, ignore previous long comment. I didn't look closely enough. It seems to matching incorrectly doesn't it. Worse than I thought. Will take a look...

Comment: Yes I think there is a problem, in the left outer join the matching seems to be done incorrectly as on lign 1 depID=NA gets a depNane=Eng and on lign2 name=Raf looses it's depName (=NA instead of Sal).

Comment: Should I repost this though or not ?

Comment: @statquant Yes please. Then it can be linked to the other NA in key questions, linked to bug report etc. It's quite distinct from this question.

Answer (score 5):

The arguments `by.x` and `by.y` are now available in the development version of `data.table`. See [here](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table). Use `devtools::install_github("Rdatatable/data.table", build_vignettes = FALSE)` to install the development version of `data.table`.

Comment: Thanks for the useful PR.

Comment: This is now version 1.9.6

Answer (score 4):

You can't because the by columns must be in the intersection of colnames(DT) and colnames(DT1)

```
 if (!all(by %in% intersect(colnames(x), colnames(y)))) {
       stop("Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y")
   }
```

Here using setnames , which which does not copy and is very fast

```
setnames(DT1,'y1','y')
> merge(DT,DT1)
   y x v x1 v1
1: 1 a 1 aa  1
2: 1 b 4 aa  1
3: 1 c 7 aa  1
4: 3 a 2 bb  2
5: 3 b 5 bb  2
6: 3 c 8 bb  2
7: 6 a 3 cc  3
8: 6 b 6 cc  3
9: 6 c 9 cc  3
```

#### EDIT update with data.table version data.table 1.9.4

you should set the `by` parameter otherwise you get an error:

```
Error in merge.data.table(DT, as.data.table(DT1)) : 
  Elements listed in `by` must be valid column names in x and y
```

You should do something like :

```
merge(DT,DT1,by="y")
```

Comment: Yes, but then I have to set back the column names...
Is there a way of doing it with `[` as I might need the `nomatch` option ?

Comment: @statquant I need to investiagte for the '[' solution. I am not a yet data.table user..Your want the '[' because it is more elegant?

Comment: Actually the `[` is faster than `merge` as merge lookup both `X` and `Y`. `data.table` is not very clear with merge stuff, it is lacking a good FAQ-merge.

Comment: @statquant Agreed, `data.table` is missing many things: 104 feature requests outstanding for example. Although, many of those are really TODO items than features per se.

Comment: @matthew I am looking at merges, I think I found a bug (may be a feature) as `merge.data.table` and `merge.data.frame` do not output same results for outer left and right joins

Comment: @statquant Good, will take a look. An email to datatable-help asking if it's a bug is the best course if possible. Questions on S.O. are not supposed to be 'specific to a point in time' - that's one of the reasons to close a question. IIUC SO etiquette. But personally I don't mind any method, just grateful for the bug report is the main thing.